# Teamcity - Signtool error - pfx file not found

Tags: teamcity, pfx, file-not-found, signtool

I have the following line in the Build Script(.bat file) :

```
SignTool.exe sign /f <Path of the .pfx file> /p "password" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /v <path of the file to be signed>
```

It works fine in the Teamcity server if run from the command line. But when the build script runs as part of the build pipeline, the following error is thrown:

**SignTool Error: File not found:**

I have confirmed that there is no issue with the Path of the file. Tried adding echo statements before this line as suggested in other forums and still no change. The same error is shown. Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Teamcity version - 2018.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved this problem
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-55093

Install the certificate on the agents and then use the command like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe" sign /v /sm /n InstalledCertificateName /d "My Tool Name" /t "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode" "%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\My Tool\bin\Release\MyTool.exe"
```

It seems that the Teamcity agent cant use a file based certificate for some reason.